# Rotating a PNG exponentially using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, rotation, exponential

I'm creating a spinning wheel game and I want to have the wheel start slow, peak at a certain speed of rotation, and then slow down again.

Any ideas for this exponential rotation speed?
Thanks!

Comment: you could use html5 canvas, see http://tech.pro/tutorial/1008/creating-a-roulette-wheel-using-html5-canvas

Answer (score 1):

Linear acceleration would cause quadratically increasing displacement, which is commonly found in nature. You should consider that as a candidate.

Regardless, I would set up your program so that you can plug in different functions to see how they look. See [jQuery easings](http://api.jqueryui.com/easings/) for an idea what this would be like.

For starters, I would try this function for angular displacement:

```
a = ct^2, for t < 3
  = c(9 - t^2), for 3 <= t < 6
  = 0, otherwise
```

Where `c` is some constant.

Answer (score 0):

A simple CSS/JS solution:

First you're going to have to create some CSS3 animations using `@keyframes`:

```
@keyframes spinningWheel{
    from {transform: rotate(0deg);}
    to {transform: rotate(360deg);}
}    
/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes spinningWheel{
    from {-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);}
    to {-webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
/* Firefox */
@-moz-keyframes spinningWheel{
    from {-moz-transform: rotate(0deg);}
    to {-moz-transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
```

Now create a CSS class that implements your animation:

```
.mySpinningWheel{
    animation-name: spinningWheel;
    -webkit-animation-name: spinningWheel;
    -moz-animation-name: spinningWheel;

    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out; /* ease-in-out is slow at the beginning and the end */
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;

    animation-iteration-count: infinite; /* this causes your wheel to spin indefinitely */
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;

    animation-duration: 5s; /* One iteration of this animation will take 5s */
    -webkit-animation-duration: 5s;
    -moz-animation-duration: 5s;     
}
```

One iteration of this animation will take 5 seconds, it will spin slowly, faster in the middle, and slowly again at the end.

To add the CSS class dynamically in JS, use jQuery's [`.addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/) function or if you aren't using jQuery, just do `document.querySelector(".selectorForYourWheel").classList.add(".mySpinningWheel")`

If you want to dynamically trigger the speed of the wheel yourself (not have it decrease and increase in speed in a single iteration, but have it be a constant speed that you can change), then change the `animation-timing-function` chunk in the CSS class from `ease-in-out` to `linear`. Then, use jQuery's [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) method to change the animation-duration (so the speed of the animation is faster or slower).